# Why this reverse function can not work in the for loop?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int prime (long n);
long reverse(long n);
int main(void)
{
    long n;
    long i, j;
    puts("Enter n dight number, and we will help you find symmetrical prime number");
    scanf("%ld", &n);
    for (i = 11; i < (pow(10, n) - 1); i+= 2)
    {
        if (prime(i))
        {
            j = reverse(i);
            if (i == j)
            {
                printf("%ld\n", i);
            }
        }        
    }
}

int prime (long n) //estimate whether the number n is primer number
{
    int status = 0;
    int j;
    //1 is prime, 0 is not
    if (n % 2 == 0 || n == 3)
    {
        if (n == 2)
            status = 1;
        if (n == 3)
            status = 1;
        else
        {
            n++;
            status = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        j = 3;
        while (j <= sqrt(n))
        {
            if (n % j == 0)
            {
                status = 0;
                break;
            }            
            else
                status = 1;
            j+= 2;
        }
    }
    return status;
}

long reverse(long n)    //reverse a number 
{
    int i, j, x;
    long k, sum;
    int digit = 0;
    int ar[1000];
    while (n > 0)
    {    
        k = n;
        n = n / 10;
        x = (k - n*10);
        digit++;
        ar[digit] = x;
    }

    for (i = 1,j = digit - 1; i <= digit; i++, j--)
    {
        sum += ar[i] * pow(10, j)
    } 

    return sum;

}
```

I build a reverse function in order to reverse numbers, for example, 214, to 412.
This function works fine in individual number, for instance, I type reverse(214), it return 412, which is good. But when I combine `reverse()` function with for loop, this function can not work... it produces some strange number...

so How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you mean `else if (n == 3)` ?

Comment: @Bathsheba, no... this prime function looks like a little strange... but let's focus on why reverse function can not work in for loop..

Comment: A note on troubleshooting this issue: A good way to go about this is to identify what might be different between the case that works and the cases that don't. For instance: Are you testing the numbers the same way? Are the test case and program being built or called differently? etc. By finding and (hopefully) eliminating discrepancies, you may be able to narrow down and find the issue or at least a more specific issue which it more generally searchable and manageable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reverse function is extremely complicated. The better way to go about it would be:

```
long reverse (long n)
{
    long result = 0;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        result *= 10;
        result += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I think the problem in your code is that in the following segment

```
  digit++;
  ar[digit] = x;
```

you first increment the position then assign to it, thus leaving `ar[0]` unintialized.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. But i am still curious about why ar[0] could influence the rest of array numbers? because even though I left ar[0] unintialized, It should not alter the rest of array..

Comment: @Annndy: I think 4386427 has it, you have left your sum uninitialized

Comment: The array indexing didn't matter as the reading starts from index 1 as well. But it is unusual and suspicious at a first glance. BTW: nice code in this answer

Answer (score 2):

> How can I fix this problem?

You need to initialize `sum`

```
long k, sum = 0;
              ^
```

See the code from @Armen Tsirunyan for a simpler approach.

Comment: well...`sum` is not a global variable, so does `sum` disappear after the `reverse` function finish? And `reverse` works fine in individual numbers, but just can not work under for loop...

Comment: Yes, `sum` "disappears" (i.e. goes out of scope) when the function returns. Local variables need to be initialized inside the function. If not they will just have some "random" value. And since your code rely on `sum` being zero to start with, you need to initialize it. Same applies to `digit` but you got that one correct :-)